# What does 'card' stands for?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I read some book where 'card' symbol is used to signify number of elements in the set. But where is it from? What the full word could be for 'card'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality)